# Javascript file is re-loaded when pressing enter button inside an <form> element. Why?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html sample code

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Form Test</title>
    <script src="./testScript.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <input id="textField" type="text" placeholder="Type in your name">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The testScript.js file contains only one line: `alert("hello");`

When I write something inside the input element and I press on enter button, the javascript file is reloaded and the alert is triggered. I noticed that when I remove the form, the reloading will not be triggered.

Why this happens? and How to prevent the reloading of javascript files when pressing enter button inside a form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without specific  attributes, the method of the form will be get, so pressing enter in an input field will submit the form through the GET method. The page will thus reload and the javascript file loaded, and the alert triggered.

Comment: Thanks @LS11, OK so the default parameter is GET method that requests the same page?I did not notice the the whole page is re-loading again, I just noticed that the javascript file is re-loaded.

Comment: Yes. If you want the form to submit to another page, you need to specify that with an action="otherpage.php" parameter.

Comment: If you add a name attribute to your input field, and press enter in it, you will notice the page has reloaded, as the URL will become yourpage.html?foo=

Answer (score -1):

I think your code exists an error.
You didn't close the input element. Just modify the html like this:

```
 <input id="textField" type="text" placeholder="Type in your name"/>
```

Comment: No, the input elements do not need closing tag.